# html to png (#extension)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Overall, I am trying to create specific pngs from one html page, that has a hrefs=# extension.  Each png should only correspond to the href# extension. 
basically:

`www.abb.org#sec1` `www.abb.org#sec2`  => `sec1.png` `sec2.ng`

I am using phantomjs.

`phantomjs rasterize.js abc.html#sec1 sec1.png` creates a png of entire html page, not specific.

Is there a way to either split a html-file into multiple html files that only contain the href #extension?  Can phantomjs somehow be configured to do this?

if the address equals some.html#sec1 it throws syntax error: however, not sure if it would work anyway(ie even if it could open with that extension.. would it just generate a single png , as what happens from commandline.)

`page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });`

`recap:` seeking to gen. multi-specific pngs from a single large html using the href #extension.

Thank you

Comment: could you elaborate on what #extension means? by definition it's an anchor used to point to specific place on a page (usually not to element) - it might be also used in single page apps for routing.